# How to `$watch` on data change and remove a class name from `DOM`

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs

In my scenario, I have active title. when other subtitle clicked by user, I am interchanging the data between it works.

when a `sub title` clicked, i am adding a class name `update`. when the update happend, i need to watch that in `active` directive and need to remove the `update` class again.

how to do this?

My HTML :

```
<div class="wrapper" ng-app="myApp">
      <div class="content" ng-controller="main">
      <active-title></active-title>
      <sub-title  item='item' index=$index ng-repeat="item in items" change="changeItem"></sub-title>
    </div>
    </div>
```

my JS :

```
// Code goes here

var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('main', ["$scope", function($scope) {
  $scope.items = [{"name":'one'},{"name":'two'},{"name":'three'}, {"name":'four'},{"name":'five'},{name:'six'}];
  $scope.activeItem = $scope.items[0];
  $scope.queueItems = $scope.items.splice(0,1);

  $scope.changeItem = function (index, item) {
    $scope.items.splice($scope.items.indexOf(item),1, $scope.activeItem);
    $scope.activeItem = item;
  }

}]);

app.directive("activeTitle", function () {
  return {
    replace : true,
    template : '<h2 class="active">{{activeItem.name}}</h2>',
    link : function (scope, element, attrs) {
        //how to $watch activeItem.name and remove the class?
        element.removeClass('change');
    }
  }
});

app.directive("subTitle", function () {
    return {
      replace:true,
      scope:{
        change :'=',
        item : '=',
        index:'='
      },
      template : '<h2>{{item.name}} {{index}}</h2>',
      link : function (scope, element, attrs) {
        var num = scope.index;
        element.on('click', function () {
          $('h2.active').addClass('change');
          scope.change(num, scope.item); 
          scope.$apply();
        })
      }
    }

})
```

[Live Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/kuFw1TXMJsqcKFgvlLy9?p=preview)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you don't create a scope for directive and you ahve a dot in model you can watch it directly from your directive

```
scope.$watch('activeItem.name', function (newValue, oldValue) {
  console.log(newValue)
})
```